# Programatically create a new order in magento for downloadable product

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento EE 1.14.0.1 where i have customize to send order to customer programmatically **BUT** for downloadable product i am not able to view link in emails send to customer. After some debug found that there is no entry in database table **downloadable_link_purchased_item** which is responsible generating links.

I tried with this code

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteId(0)
->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
->setBase_currency_code('USD')
->setStore_currency_code('USD')
->setOrder_currency_code('USD');
//Set your store currency USD or any other
// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
->setCustomer($customer);
// set Billing Address
$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
->setCity($billing->getCity())
->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
->setFax($billing->getFax());
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);
$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
->setCity($shipping->getCity())
->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
->setFax($shipping->getFax());
$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
->setMethod('checkmo')
->setPo_number(' – ');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);
$subTotal = 0;
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productData->getEntityId());
$rowTotal = 0;
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteItemId(0)
->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
->setProductId($productData->getEntityId())
->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
->setTotalQtyOrdered(1)
->setQtyOrdered(1)
->setName($_product->getName())
->setSku($_product->getSku())
->setPrice(0)
->setBasePrice(0)
->setOriginalPrice(0)
->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);
$subTotal += $rowTotal;
$order->addItem($orderItem);
$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);
$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
$order_mail = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$incrementId = $orders;
$order_mail->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
try
{
$order_mail->sendNewOrderEmail();
} 

catch (Exception $ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? You will likely get answers if you show what you have tried.

Comment: modified code added this and working now Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after', array('order'=>$orderObj, 'quote'=>$quoteObj));